# Best way of naming database according location

Tags: java, android, sql-server, database, oracle

I am building an app that contains details of users in a database and those details are accessible to all other users too. I want to make it easy for users to find others database. So i decided to name the users database according to locations, so that they always see users nearby to them by default. They can view any other user by searching the location.

But what is the best way for grouping the database. A few possibilities that i thought is grouping database according to district, taluk or panchayath. Can you share a better idea? Thanks in Advance to the great souls!

Comment: 'Database' means different things in Oracle and SQL Server, so from an Oracle perspective it's not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting your data in regional databases would be a good usecase when all actions would be selfcontained in a certain region. Very often this is not the case, so in the modern database design distributed databases win over sharded ones. The sharded model becomes a big hurdle when your usecases change or grow.

Geospatial Indexing comes to the rescue and makes it much easier to implement features on user proximity.